# how to write to a file when it's an executable in java

Tags: java, file, input, stream, output

**HI**
I have a problem with writing to files, It works in the program(netbeans), but when it's exported to a jar file, it throws an exception, "FileNotFound." I checked inside the file folder inside the jar, and it was there, I think I need to use streams just as I use them in reading files:
`InputStream  u=  FM.class.getResourceAsStream("/genex/files/data.txt");
try (InputStreamReader f = new InputStreamReader(u)) {what I wrote}`

and that works perfectly fine, I just need a method like a getResourceAsStream() for OutputStreams

(btw, FM is the class name)

**UPDATE:** For those of you who really wanted to write files inside the jar, well, it's *impossible*. **BUT,** I found another way to store all of your files:
-writing

```
File file = new File("/GH/GX/save.txt");
     if (!file.exists()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
            file.createNewFile();
    }

try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)) {what you want to write}
```

-reading

```
    File file = new File("/GH/GX/save.txt");
     if (!file.exists()) {
            return;
    }

            try (FileReader f = new FileReader(file)) {

                //fr = new FileReader(f);
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f)) {what you want to read}}
```

So I hope this article helped you :)

Comment: How can you possibly edit the file inside your JAR?

Comment: Are you trying to write to a file in a jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only read from files inside a jar not write to them.